# Where to ask basic questions about machine learning?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am a beginner in machine learning.

I have very basic doubts and confusions. On which site can I ask such questions related to machine learning?

Comment: Related for expert questions on machine learning: [Which StackExchange website for Machine Learning and computational algorithms?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stackexchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 production sites: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), [stats.se](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), and [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/). There is some overflow between the sites, but at one extreme if your question is purely about an aspect of coding, use stackoverflow, and at the other extreme if your question is purely about an aspect of the maths, using maths.se. So for example, if you can't figure out the right way to organize your data prior to calling a regression library, use stackoverflow, but if your question is about how to use calculus to figure out a gradient in order to efficiently minimize your errors then use maths.se.

Stats.se (cross-validated) overlaps with both sites. Questions there often have some sort of programming element to them (especially in R or other statistical languages), but in the context of a statistical or machine learning problem. It's also a good place to ask question on topics including methodology, how to choose features, interpreting results, and the mathematics behind the algorithms.

All of these sites welcome questions from beginners, so long as they meet the sites' standards -- which in general means looking for solutions first *especially on the site itself*, describing a *specific* on-topic problem, and, where appropriate, the steps you have taken, or would take, to attempt to solve it. To get a good idea of the kinds of questions and answers on the different sites, you can look at the machine-learning tag on each site.

I'm not familiar with Computer Science, as mentioned in [TGMClans' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227757/where-to-ask-basic-questions-about-machine-learning/227759#227759). But Browsing through the [Computer Science questions tagged machine learning](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) seems to confirm the description of Computer Science questions given in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165400)

> As a rule of thumb, if your question depends on code, ask on Stack Overflow; if your question calls for mathematical notation, ask on Computer Science. Algorithms expressed in pseudocode straddle the border.

You do, however, need to choose just one site for each question: don't cross-post. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) for more information.

Finally, here is a quantitative overview of the number of questions on the different sites.

[image]

Sources: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/topusers), [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/machine-learning/topusers), [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/machine-learning/topusers), [compsci](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/machine-learning/topusers)

Note that "unanswered" is a little misleading as it includes question which have answers with no votes, and also questions which are essentially answered in comments (this is particularly common on stats.se).

(Here is a related question on maths.se meta: [Which site is better to ask question about Machine Learning](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13120/which-site-is-better-to-ask-question-about-machine-learning)?)

Comment: April 2022 - there is very little on Cross-validated for applied ML. They dont even have a tag for `cnn`. If you need to talk to people who understands ML on high-level you are always at great disadvantage on Cross-validated because it is owned by people who only know statistics (and they dont care to learn anything else and attacking everyone who doesnt fit the *profile*). And SO is now completely unusable by the sheer amount of micro-groups of zealots trying to protect their sandcastles. Questions got closed or downvoted to oblivion for no good reason. So where do I ask about Bayesian CNNs ?

Answer (score 3):

You can ask here [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) , [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) and here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning).

Comment: I am quite low standard , i mean just beginner ,is it okay for me ?

Comment: If you show that you have tried to solve your own problems first (show attempted solutions, show results of web searches), it should be OK. Take care that your questions can be answered objectively though; do not ask [Gorilla vs Shark questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Aspects of machine learning are now part of our [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), but check out the specifics of scope:

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> If you have a question about...
>
> - social issues in a world where artificial intelligence is common,
> - conceptual aspects of AI, or
> - human factors in AI development
>
> ...and it is not about...
>
> - the implementation of machine learning, or
> - asking for a development tool or career path recommendation
>
> ...then you're in the right place to ask your question!