# On which SE should one post questions relating to deep learning?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Practical, yet not code-related, questions about deep learning: where should they be posted?
As far as I can tell, they should go either on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Theoretical cs and cs seem to be candidates as well

Comment: @gnat: Since the answer mentions neither of the sites, I'm not sure that's the best dupe.

Comment: @NathanTuggy it's a canonical FQA meaning it is expected to be updated if something is considered worth adding to it

Comment: @gnat: Yes, but duping to a FAQ that a) doesn't *necessarily* have to contain the same scope and b) doesn't currently cover the necessary information isn't a great idea, IMO.

Comment: A better dup target is http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130524/160917; it explicitly covers machine learning (deep learning is just an answer of that, so this is covered by the answers there).