# Should a Stack Exchange site be created exclusively for machine learning?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51

I found in this question:

[Which Stack Exchange website for machine learning and computational algorithms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms)

When trying to ask a Machine learning question it is not entirely clear where to ask it. It can be theoretical (use TCS) or practical (Cross-Validated or Data Science). It seems like a mess to me!

Would it be appropriate to propose a new machine learning site at Area 51?

Have there been other spin-off sites in the past?

Comment: There is already an ai.stackexchange.com, I think it would be better if it would grow first.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the above comment, but, you know, [there's only one way to find out](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been tried a few times: [1](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41738/machine-learning), [2](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26434/machine-learning).
These proposals for a Machine Learning SE went into private beta, but did not live beyond that. 
I participated in one of these. When that particular proposal was closed, the questions were migrated to [Cross Validated](https://statistics.stackexchange.com).

It appears that Machine Learning is just too specialized to make a viable Stack Exchange site.

Fortunately, most machine learning questions can be asked on Cross Validated or [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com).
As always, check their Help Center before posting, to make sure that your question is on-topic on the chosen site.

Comment: To add to the list, [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) also appears to be a popular destination for implementation questions about machine learning. I kinda wish AI.SE would allow implementation questions as well, so that one site could host design, implementation, and conceptual questions.