# Where can we ask encoding-related questions which are not related to security or encryption?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question, related to encoding for machine learning. I tried on the encryption Stack Exchange site, but it was not related to encryption.

So where should I ask such a question?

Comment: @rene seems like a mis dupe?; he seems to just need a Stack overflow explanation of some encoding, nothing about ML.

Comment: Does this help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms if not can you please clarify what your exact question is about?

Comment: @SomethingBadHappened well, you must be way better at guessing then ... ;

Comment: It might conceivably be on-topic on CrossValidated as long as it is about the underlying theory not actual code.